# CREATE EXTENSION postgis returns error?

Tags: postgis, installation

When I issue "CREATE EXTENSION postgis", I'm getting :

> curs.execute('CREATE EXTENSION postgis')
>   psycopg2.InternalError: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.3.so": /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.3.so.0: undefined symbol: GEOSClipByRect**

I use psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1. Does anybody know how can I fix it?

---

I use following comments for installing postgis.

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2 pgadmin3 postgresql-contrib-9.5

Comment: Questions about using PostGIS with GIS software are on topic here in GIS SE, but install issues are better researched in the DBA exchange. As a relatively new user, pease take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please format code in a code block and quotes in quote blocks.

Comment: do you have installed both postgres 9.5 and 9.6 on your OS? because it seems like python path conflict

Comment: Please give more details about your installation process.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if you compiled PostGIS with a newer version of GEOS than what you have in your install path.

If you installed your PostGIS from a package, you probably just need to do an apt-get update, apt-get upgrade

The psycopg2 error I'm assuming is because you are installing via python and not at all the issue.